# I'm trying to make a wild west game with pygame, but I can't get the shooting functions to work

Tags: pygame, 2d

I've been trying to make a wild west game in Pygame in which the player duels an NPC, but I can't get the shooting functions to work. I've basically tried to keep it simple, and I have a series of functions to make the bullet go across the screen, but they aren't working. Here's the code:

```
import pygame, time
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Old Wild West')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dead = False
avatar = pygame.image.load('cowboy.jfif')
avatar2 = pygame.image.load('enemy.jfif')
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bx2 = 330
bx3 = 440
bx4 = 550
bx = 220
by = 220
bspeed = 165
x =  50
ex = 550
ey = 225
y = 200
x_change = 0
speed = 0

def cowboy(x,y):
    win.blit(avatar, (x,y))
def enemy(ex, ey):
    win.blit(avatar2, (ex, ey))
def shootframe1():
    win.blit(bullet, (bx, by))
def antiframe1():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (bx, by, 50, 150))
def shootframe2():
    win.blit(bullet, (bx2, by))
def antiframe2():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (bx2, by, 50, 150))
def shootframe3():
    win.blit(bullet, (bx3, by))
def antiframe3():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (bx3, by, 50, 150))
def shootframe4():
    win.blit(bullet, (bx4, by))
def antiframe4():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (bx4, by, 50, 150))
  
while not dead:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                shootframe1()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                antiframe1()
                shootframe2()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                antiframe2()
                shootframe3()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                antiframe3()
                shootframe4()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                antiframe4()
        
   x += x_change

   win.fill(white)
   cowboy(x,y)
   enemy(ex, ey)

    
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Here is cowboy.jfif, enemy.jfif and bullet.png:

[bullet.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMak.png)

[cowboy.jfif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sARXg.jpg)

[enemy.jfif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg6Ve.jpg)

Please help me out with this confusion.

Comment: Can you please specify what the issue is exactly?

Comment: You could start by removing the line `if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE`.  There's no event *type* of 'K_SPACE'.

Comment: i want to make the picture bullet.png go across the screen when the player presses space, but it isn't working. That's the problem.

Comment: I tried removing `if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't remove it. There's no event *type* of  `pygame.K_SPACE`, but there is a event *key* with that constant. You probably meant to do `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN`, and **then** `if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman - Yeah, the OP has that on the line below the one I suggested removing.

Comment: @Kingsley Ah, I see what you meant now

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code drastically, I tried to comment everything pretty well so it's clear what is happening.

First, you were filling the screen white after drawing the bullet onto the screen so it never showed up.

Second, the space bar key didn't fire because you were checking if the space bar was an event type. So I moved it under the `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN`

Third, using time.sleep(0.5) makes the game window freeze and stutter a lot so I would avoid doing that.

If you have any questions about the changes feel free to ask.

```py
import pygame, time
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Old Wild West')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dead = False
avatar = pygame.image.load('cowboy.jfif')
avatar2 = pygame.image.load('enemy.jfif')
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bx2 = 330
bx3 = 440
bx4 = 550
bx = 220
by = 220
bspeed = 165
x =  50
ex = 550
ey = 225
y = 200
x_change = 0
speed = 0

def cowboy(x,y):
    win.blit(avatar, (x,y))
def enemy(ex, ey):
    win.blit(avatar2, (ex, ey))

# A single shoot function that appends a new bullet to our bullet list below.
def shoot():
    bullet_list.append(Bullet(bx, by))

# A bullet class that holds information about a single bullet
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Initializing variables for the bullet
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
        self.bullet_speed = 165

    # Moves the bullet accross the screen by updating the x variable after each draw()
    def _move_bullet(self):
        self.x += self.bullet_speed

    def draw(self):
        # Get the surface (window)
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        # Blit the bullet to the screen
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        # Update its position with the function above
        self._move_bullet()

bullet_list = [] # Since the user can have multiple bullets firing, we need to keep track of them
while not dead:
    win.fill(white) #Move this to the top so you're filling the screen before drawing anything
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: # Moved this up here
                shoot() # Spawn the bullet
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    cowboy(x,y)
    enemy(ex, ey)

    # Draw each bullet onto the screen by iterating over the list
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        # If the bullet has exited the screen we remove it from the list so they are not kept in memory
        if bullet.x > display_width:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        # Draw the bullet (called from the Class)
        bullet.draw()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```